# HDFS Metadata is taking too much space

Tags: hadoop, hbase, metadata, hdfs

I am trying to migrate data from SQL Database to HBase with Hadoop. But the problem is my database is of 70 GB in SQL and it takes around 400 GB when I have transferred it to Hadoop. Why it is so ?. Is there any way to reduce this space used.

Also how much disk space is required if I have a data of SQL database of 800 GB.

Comment: What is the replication factor in HDFS? If replication factor is 3 (which is default), then 70 GB will be 70 * 3 = 210 GB. Meta data should not consume much space.

Comment: Hello Manjunath, thanks for the quick reply. As I told I am new to Hadoop, My Cluster is configured with Hadoop Federation i.e. with One Master, One StandyBy Master and one Slave. So how much replication factor is required for this. Also what is the main reason behind these much of Space consumption.

Comment: By default replication factor is set to 3. It means, 3 copies of every file are created. So, your copied data will be at least 3 times the original data. I am not sure why it it taking 400 GB. It should not take that much space.

Comment: So can I change this replication factor to 2 or 1 such that it don't affect Hadoop Federation Cluster configuration ???

Comment: Yes. You can change the replication factor to 2 or 1. But, your jobs may not run efficiently, since Hadoop distributes the processing across the cluster and moves compute to data. Also, if replication is set to just 1 and if a node goes down, you may lose some data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a large amount of serach, I come across some results that I am storing my data in default format of Hadoop i.e. text format. So, It will consume large amount of space for storing data compare to other Storage. Also Manjunath is correct as we reduce the replication factor, It might reduce the storage space but it will cause some problems as well. For further information on this topic, kindly refer to the below mentioned link :

http://datametica.com/rcorc-file-format/